# connect four matlab

Tags: matlab, connect-four

Ok, right now i'm trying to create a connect four game through Matlab coding; now the game is still infant but my problem is that I either can't get the figure to plot in each grid square or I can't get the 'circle' figure to plot at all. Please help in any way possible. Also if anyone knows about any connect four matlab tutorials, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
  function [] = Kinect4(nrRows, nrCols)
  board = zeros(nrRows, nrCols);

  nrMoves = 0;

        set(gca, 'xlim', [0 nrCols]);
        set(gca, 'ylim', [0 nrRows]);

        for r = 1 : 1 : nrRows - 1
        line([0, nrCols], [r, r], ...
        'LineWidth', 4, 'Color', [0 0 1]);
        end

        for c = 1 : 1 : nrCols - 1
        line([c, c], [0, nrRows], ...
        'LineWidth', 4, 'Color', [0 0 1]);
        end

  DrawBoard(nrRows, nrCols)
  hold on;

  while nrMoves < nrRows * nrCols                    %Computes ability to move polygon
       [x, y] = ginput(1); 
        r = ceil(y); % convert to row index
        c = ceil(x); % convert to column index

angles = 0 : 1 : 360;
        x = cx + r .* cosd(angles);
        y = cy + r .* sind(angles);

        plot(x, y, 'Color', [1 1 1], 'LineWidth', 3);
        axis square;
  end 
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some fixes to the code.

1. removed the line `DrawBoard(nrRows, nrCols)`. Not sure if you put it there as a comment as you have already drawn the board or if `DrawBoard` is a separate function.
2. Changed the calculation for `r` and `c` to give the center of the cell you wan the put the peg in. This is done by subtracting 0.5 from each.
3. Changed the line `x = cx + r .* cosd(angles);` to `x = c + 0.5*cosd(angles);`. In the previous one, variable `cx` is undefined and instead of `r` being the radius of the peg, I used `0.5` you can replace it by appropriate variable. But the idea is to draw a circle of radius `0.5` (so that it fits in a cell) with the center offset by `c` along x-axis. Similar change for `y` to offset the peg along y-axis.
4. Changed the color in `plot` command to `[0 0 0]`, which is black. `[1 1 1]` is white and is impossible to see on white background :). I would suggest using `'k'` for black, `'b'` for blue and so on. See matlab documentation for basic color specifications.
5. I am guessing you are yet to implement gravity so that the peg moves down. Also you need to check is a cell is already filled. All these and other improvements (like removing unnecessary for-loops, better way to draw pegs, etc.) are left once you get to a working code.

Here's a "working" code:

```
function [] = Kinect4(nrRows, nrCols)
    board = zeros(nrRows, nrCols);

    nrMoves = 0;

        set(gca, 'xlim', [0 nrCols]);
        set(gca, 'ylim', [0 nrRows]);

        for r = 1 : 1 : nrRows - 1
            line([0, nrCols], [r, r], ...
            'LineWidth', 4, 'Color', [0 0 1]);
        end

        for c = 1 : 1 : nrCols - 1
            line([c, c], [0, nrRows], ...
            'LineWidth', 4, 'Color', [0 0 1]);
        end

        axis square;
        hold on;

    while nrMoves < nrRows * nrCols        %Computes ability to move polygon
        [x, y] = ginput(1); 
        r = ceil(y) - 0.5;
        c = ceil(x) - 0.5;

        angles = 0 : 1 : 360;
        x = c + 0.5*cosd(angles);
        y = r + 0.5*sind(angles);

        plot(x, y, 'Color', [0 0 0], 'LineWidth', 3);
    end 
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. My next question though is how would you implement gravity and check that the cell is already filled? I don't need the exact coding, but direction to how to do it would be very grateful.

Comment: @FunnyBro777 There are many ways to do this. A visual way would be to use the `board` martix to keep track of cells that have been filled. So if  a cell is occupied the corresponding element will be non zero. When the player enters next move, `ginput` will only care about the column (`x`) location and replace the flip the last zero element in that column of `board` matrix. You can flip it to 1 or 2 to keep track of which player had made the move.

Comment: Another option would be to use a row vector and just increment the corresponding column by one every time the player makes a move. You will need t draw the player's move immediately as there is no way to keep track of the moves made.

Comment: Okay your explanation made much more sense than what I've been reading/researching. Thanks so much for your help